# What is the difference between chickens and birds?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ornithology

I watched news about turkeys this morning and instead of calling them chickens the news anchor called them birds.

In my opinion, turkeys are sub-type of chickens. They are not a bird because they cannot fly. (In my native language, most birds can fly.)

What is the difference between chickens and birds? Why did they call turkeys birds, not chickens?

Comment: This is a question on taxonomy in biology forum. If you opine that Turkeys are a sub-type of Chickens, or that birds that cannot fly should not be called birds, in that forum, you might get quite a few LOLs or even voted down. Read up on the taxonomy of Turkey from wikipedia. BTW, penguin is a bird. Please, I beg you, read up from wikipedia before making such LOLable opinions.

Comment: Chickens are birds, too. Both turkeys and chickens are *poultry* (which may be the word you're looking for).

Comment: Ostriches and emus can't fly but they are classed as birds too. @PeterShor answer, **poultry**, is probably what you meant instead of *chicken*. You could edit your question, and  explain that in your language (which is?) turkeys are not considered to be poultry. If that were true. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poultry

Comment: @BlessedGeek You don't get the point of my question and mislead the question.n I ask this question in context of the English language. In my language (Thai), we call chickens chickens and call turkeys turkeys chickens (this is just an example, the main idea is we have the word chickens in turkeys my native language.) It's OK if this question makes you laugh but I highly recommend you jump out of your own thought and try to learn or explore why people from different location call or perceive the same thing differently.

Comment: Pls don't apply Thai language nuances to English. Even Thai language has to conform to scientific conventions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a mistaken notion that being a bird has something to do with flight, or that poultry cannot fly. This is biological nonsense.

Comment: @BlessedGeek, I think, the taxonomy of Turkey belongs rather to geography. :-) As for the question, the classification needn't be biological. There are classification of goods for trade, of weights for transport, of poultry for growing it up, and so on. And in different classifications the same thing can have different names. And they needn't conform to each other, you have mistaken. And names systems definitely belong to the language, this time the English one... The question, obviously, caused by misunderstanding and contents some error, but that is not the reason for downvote.

Comment: I never downvote. Never except when someone writes in horribly incomprehensible or pidginated English.

Answer (score 6):

I assure you turkeys can fly.  As a matter of fact the first you hear/see/feel on in flight, you'll remember it.  They are loud and a little scary.  A chicken is Gallus gallus or Gallus domesticus.  A turkey belongs to the species Meleagris galloparvo.  Both are birds, belonging to the class Avis.  Taxonomically, they are classified in the same family.  Many chickens, Gallus spp., can and do fly, although it is obvious why they are not bred for flight.

Comment: The question is a good one.  It is not surprising that there is not a word-for-word translation for chicken/bird/fowl back and forth between languages.  These animals occupy different roles in different location.  I had a friend once who did not speak English, but would argue that pigeons and chickens were the same thing.  To make the issue even more complex, the taxonomy of various species changes from time to time.

Comment: Wild turkeys fly but domesticated ones, i.e. those bred on farms, cannot. Your answer is a *little* misleading. http://www.nwtf.org/all_about_turkeys/wild_turkey_facts.html

Comment: [As God is my witness...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FXSnoy71Q4)

Comment: The flying ability of turkeys doesn't depend on whether they are wild or domesticated. It depends on their weight. Young domesticated turkeys can fly just as well as wild ones. If a wild turkey was artificially fattened to twice it's normal size, it wouldn't be able to get off the ground, either.

Answer (score 3):

A bird is any member of the class *Aves*.  Chickens (*Gallus gallus domesticus*) and turkeys (*Meleagris gallopavo*) are both galliform ("chicken-like") birds, but they are not at all similar.  Turkeys are much larger, up to 40 kg although typically around 10 kg, compared to chicken, which are a quarter as heavy.  More importantly, chickens are tastier than turkeys.

Being able to fly, although common among birds is neither universal among them (think about penguins, ostriches, kiwis and dodos), nor unique to them.  Bats, many insects, and pterosaurs can fly, and there are gliding species of squirrels, primates, fish, squids, spiders, and horrifyingly, snakes.